# Adding a ContextMenu to a ListView<File> results in empty rows showing null

Tags: listview, javafx, contextmenu

I'm using a CellFactory to add a ContextMenu to a ListView as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264907/javafx-listview-contextmenu).  I'm using a `ListView<File>` instead of `ListView<String>`.  The problem is that empty rows in the ListView show "null".  This is caused by the line

`cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty().asString());`

but I can't leave that out or else all rows are blank even when the row is not empty.

What's the correct way to bind the cell.textProperty() to not display null when the row is empty?

```
public class FileUploaderVBox extends VBox {

    ListView<File> filesToUpload = new ListView<>();

    public FileUploaderVBox(Stage primaryStage) {
        setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

        Label l = new Label("Select Files to Upload");
        l.setStyle("-fx-font: 12 arial; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
        setMargin(l, new Insets(25,0,20,0));

        Separator horizSeparator1 = new Separator();
        horizSeparator1.prefWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());


        filesToUpload.setCellFactory(lv -> {

            ListCell<File> cell = new ListCell<>();

            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();


            MenuItem deleteItem = new MenuItem();
            deleteItem.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Delete \"%s\"", cell.itemProperty()));
            deleteItem.setOnAction(event -> filesToUpload.getItems().remove(cell.getItem()));

            contextMenu.getItems().addAll(deleteItem);

//            cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());
            cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty().asString());

        cell.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
            if (isNowEmpty) {
                cell.setContextMenu(null);
            } else {
                cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
            }
        });

            return cell ;
        });

        Separator horizSeparator2 = new Separator();
        horizSeparator2.prefWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());

        Button chooseFileButton = new Button("Choose File");

        chooseFileButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent> () {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
                File f = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
                if (null != f)
                    filesToUpload.getItems().add(f);
            }
        });

        getChildren().addAll(l, horizSeparator1, filesToUpload, horizSeparator2, chooseFileButton);

    }

    public ObservableList<File> getFilesToUpload() {
        return filesToUpload.getItems();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Replacing `cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty().asString())` with the following gives a StackOverflowError.

```
    ObjectProperty<File> itemProperty = cell.itemProperty();
    StringBinding sb = Bindings.createStringBinding(new Callable<String>() {

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {

            if (null == itemProperty)
                return "";
            else
                return itemProperty.toString();
        }

    }, itemProperty);

    cell.textProperty().bind(sb);
```

What the heck?

Comment: The call to `toString()` causes the stack overflow.  In the `call()` method replace `itemProperty` with `itemProperty.toString()` solves the stack overflow and eliminates the `null` in the empty rows in the ListView.

Comment: Submitted a bug to Oracle:  9049978

Comment: Oracle accepted my bug report.  This also happens in Java 9.  http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8184320

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
StringBinding stringBinding = new StringBinding(){
      {
       super.bind(cell.itemProperty().asString());
      }
      @Override
      protected String computeValue() {
          if(cell.itemProperty().getValue()==null){
              return "";
          }
          return cell.itemProperty().getValue().getPath();
     }
};

cell.textProperty().bind(stringBinding);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, because `asString` for `null` should return `"null"`, not an empty string. But doesn't `ListCell` have an `empty` property? Alternatively, you should be able to bind to a null-check.

Comment: `Bindings.when` is a BooleanBinding

Comment: Your latest code shows "item" in every row, whether empty or not.

Comment: @DeanSchulze I fixed , Now it should work as it's shown above in the gif.