# Javafx how to get cell from list(not value)

Tags: javafx

I want get the cell(node,not data) from list by index.I need cast it to my custom cell and call its function.

I found a lot of question ask how to get value,but i find nothing about how to get cell itself.I try to use `listView.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(index)`,but it's not work.

The function i want to achieve is right clicking on the cell of list,then popup a context menu which have a 'rename' command,when i clicking the commond, `startEdit` function of cell need to be called.

How can i do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but you can register mouse listeners (or set context menus) on cells in a cell factory. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264907/javafx-listview-contextmenu get you in the right direction?

Comment: I understand your meaning,but I have registered context menu on list,if there are no other way to get cell directly,I can only registered context menu on each cell but i don't think it's a good solution.Whatever,thank you.

Comment: Why is it not a good solution to register a context menu on each cell?

Comment: Because listview is a field in of my controller,set context menu on it i can call other methods easyily

Comment: There's absolutely no reason a context menu on the cell couldn't call another "function" (you mean "method", surely?) in the controller. I think you need to post some code to demonstrate what the problem is.

Comment: I understand you meaning. Just because i have write a lot of code so adjust context menu to the cell is harder then i just get cell and call it's method if it's possible,if there are no other way,i can only do a transfer

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment. What is a "transfer"?

Comment: If there are no other way i will choose your way,but it's will take more time to achieve because I have a lot of code relative to contextmenu.Sorry i'm poor in english:).

Comment: There is no other way, other than  some hacks which would make your code unmaintainable. You should register the context menus on the individual cells; that's the intended approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the context menu on the individual cells, not on the list view itself. Here is a quick example:

Controller class with list view, and methods to invoke from context menu items:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView ;

    public void initialize() {
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 20 ; i++) {
            listView.getItems().add("Item "+i);
        }
        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCellWithContextMenu(this));
    }

    public void edit(int index) {
        listView.edit(index);
    }

    public void delete(int index) {
        listView.getItems().remove(index);
    }
}
```

The cell implementation:

```
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldListCell;

public class ListCellWithContextMenu extends TextFieldListCell<String> {


    private final ContextMenu contextMenu ;

    public ListCellWithContextMenu(Controller controller) {
        contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem delete = new MenuItem("Delete");
        MenuItem edit = new MenuItem("Edit");
        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(edit, delete);

        edit.setOnAction(e -> controller.edit(getIndex()));
        delete.setOnAction(e -> controller.delete(getIndex()));

        setConverter(TextFormatter.IDENTITY_STRING_CONVERTER);

    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setContextMenu(null);
        } else {
            setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness, an FXML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
    <left>
        <ListView fx:id="listView" editable="true" />
    </left>
</BorderPane>
```

and an application class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewWithContextMenu extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ListViewWithContextMenu.fxml")));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response and you are absolute right,but I chose a more suitable way for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

James_D is right,you can register the context menus on the individual cells.
But in the situation which i have a lot of code relative to context menu,rewrite then all may cause other problems.After some try i use a another way.

For simplicity,I write two reusable class to implement the function that get cell by index from list directly.

If you think helpful,you can use the code below.

```
  //let your cell extend this class
 public class GetAbleListCell<T> extends ListCell<T>{

    private ListViewHelper<T> libraryListHelper;

    public GetAbleListCell(ListViewHelper<T> libraryListHelper) {
        this.libraryListHelper = libraryListHelper;


    }

    @Override
    public void updateIndex(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.updateIndex(i);

        if(getIndex()>0)
        {
            libraryListHelper.setCell(getIndex(),this);
        }
    }

}
 //helper class 
public class ListViewHelper<T> {

    private ObservableList<GetAbleListCell<T>> list=FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    public GetAbleListCell<T> getCell(int index) {

        return list.get(index);
    }



    public void setCell(int index, GetAbleListCell<T> getAbleListCell) {
        while(list.size()<index+1)
        {
        list.add(null);
        }
        list.set(index, getAbleListCell);

    }

}
```

example

```
this.libraryListHelper=new ListViewHelper();
libraryLV.setCellFactory(param -> new LibraryCell(libraryListHelper));
.........
private void renameCurrentSelectedItems() {
        //get cell directly
        LibraryCell cell=(LibraryCell) libraryListHelper.getCell(libraryLV.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        cell.startEdit();
    }
```

may contain some bug but it work in my situation