# How do I set a context menu around a whole object

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

See if you look at the image, I can only right click and get a context menu when I click in the orange area. I want to be able to right click and get a context menu when I click around the whole object (like in the progress bar and etc). All those items in the orange are displayed using a List View, I am using Hbox to organize them so checkbox and progress bar can be on the some line. I tried this answer [Javafx ListView ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264907/javafx-listview-contextmenu) but it didn't really help.  [image: Problem]

Here's my code

```
// Declare list that will hold the item
    ObservableList<HBox> itemList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    // Declare List View that will contain all the items
    ListView itemlistView = new ListView<>();
    // Get the items within the week
    VBitem.displayByWeek();
    // Add the items to the item list
    for (int i = 0; i < VBitem.weekList.size(); i++) {
        itemList.add(VBitem.weekList.get(i).display());
    }
    // Add the items to the list view
    itemlistView.setitems(itemList);
    // Style the list
    itemlistView.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Main.css").toExternalForm());
    // Add the list view to the scroll pane
    fx_content_scroll.setContent(itemlistView);

    itemlistView.setCellFactory(ly -> {
        ListCell<HBox> cell = new ListCell<>();
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        // Menu items
        Menuitem editMenu = new Menuitem("Edit");
        Menuitem deleteMenu = new Menuitem("Delete");



        //System.out.println("Cell " + cell.getitem().item.info());
        editMenu.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Edit \"%s\"",cell.itemProperty()));
        //edititem.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Edit \"%s\"", cell.itemProperty()));
        //editMenu.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty().asString());
        editMenu.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("HI "+cell.itemProperty());
            //System.out.println("Just edited "+cell.getitem().item.info());
            System.out.println("Editing");
        });
        // Add menu items to ContextMenu
        contextMenu.getitems().addAll(editMenu, deleteMenu);



        cell.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
            if (isNowEmpty) {
                cell.setContextMenu(null);
            } else {
                cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
            }
        });

        return cell;

    });
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to make the problem more clear?

Comment: HBox is a Node. It seems to me that you added check box and progress bar to your HBox. Am I right?

Comment: @zlakad yes, HBox(Check,Progressbar), that's how the item is created

Comment: @Zachary I would but it is duplicate code from the answer I linked in the question

Comment: The code in the linked question doesn't have a checkbox, or a progress bar, and the context menu appears when right-clicking on the entire cell. So the linked code doesn't demonstrate the issue at all.

Comment: @Zachary I added my code

Comment: @James_D I added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to show a ContextMenu anywhere within the Pane that contains the CheckBox and the ProgressBar. Adding a ContextMenu to a Control is straight forward; you use the `Control.setContextMenu(...);` method, however, an HBox is a Pane, not a control.

To add a ContextMenu to a HBox, you can use the [`Node.setOnContextMenuRequested(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnContextMenuRequested-javafx.event.EventHandler-) method to receive an event when the ContextMenu is requested. During which you can show the context menu at the event location, giving the desired effect.

```
    HBox box = new HBox();
    box.getChildren().addAll(...);        

    MenuItem editMenu = new MenuItem("Edit");
    editMenu.setOnAction(e -> {
        // Do something
    });

    MenuItem deleteMenu = new MenuItem("Delete");
    deleteMenu.setOnAction(e -> {
        // Do something
    });

    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(editMenu, deleteMenu);
    box.setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> {
        menu.show(box.getScene().getWindow(), e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
    });
```

This will open a ContextMenu anywhere within the HBox you used to organize the CheckBox and the ProgressBar. This can easily be adjusted to fit to your desired area.

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I wanted :D