# JavaFX can not clear items from listview

Tags: java, listview, javafx, fxml

I'm using a ListView in my project and wanted to add a context menu to each list item so that each can be removed individually. When using the following code this appears to work just fine:

```
postList.setCellFactory(lv -> {
            ListCell<Result> cell = new ListCell<>();
            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

            StringBinding stringBinding = new StringBinding() {
                {
                    super.bind(cell.itemProperty().asString());
                }

                @Override
                protected String computeValue() {
                    if (cell.itemProperty().getValue() == null) {
                        return "";
                    }
                    return cell.itemProperty().getValue().getTitle();
                }
            };
            cell.textProperty().bind(stringBinding);

            MenuItem deleteItem = new MenuItem();
            deleteItem.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Delete item"));
            deleteItem.setOnAction(event -> postList.getItems().remove(cell.getItem()));
            contextMenu.getItems().addAll(openPermalink, openSubreddit, openURL, deleteItem);

            cell.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
                if (isNowEmpty) {
                    cell.setContextMenu(null);
                } else {
                    cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
                }
            });

            return cell;
        });
```

However, after clearing the post list - although the items appear to be removed - when another is added all of the removed items re-appear and the item to be added is not displayed.

Any items what could be causing this? It only happens when I set the cell factory and is fine otherwise.

I recorded a small gif to help better explain the issue:
[image: Adding and clearing items]

Thank you!

Edit: It appears that the issue is mainly to do with this segment

```
StringBinding stringBinding = new StringBinding() {
                {
                    super.bind(cell.itemProperty().asString());
                }

                @Override
                protected String computeValue() {
                    if (cell.itemProperty().getValue() == null) {
                        return "";
                    }
                    return cell.itemProperty().getValue().getTitle();
                }
            };
```

As is seems that even though the items are there they have an empty display title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javafx ListView ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264907/javafx-listview-contextmenu)

Comment: The code I use is adapted from there but the issue is entirely different

Comment: What did you do differently in your code? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've edited the post with some further probing I've done and narrowed down the issue to that specific snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `ListCell.updateItem()` workflow instead of the `StringBinding` it should work:

```
        ListCell< Result > cell = new ListCell< Result >() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null) {
                    setText(item.getValue());
                } else {
                    setText("");
                }
            }
        };
```

Your binding workflow seems to create an unnecessary dependency which blocks deletion.

---

P.S.: why do you use binding for static text in `deleteItem`? Just assign the value directly:

```
        MenuItem deleteItem = new MenuItem();
        deleteItem.setText("Delete item");
```

Comment: This appears to have solved the issue, thanks for the solution and advice!